# Adding Windows Authentication to a React + ASP.Net App

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

Hey guys I was just wondering if any knew how to add user authentication to a react app? All the resources ive seen online are either outdated or don't work at all (at least in my research so far). THE closest I have gotten it to work was the backend being able to identify the currently logged in user. But all the API calls my react app makes to the back end all end up failing due to being unauthorized. Any help would be really appreciated.

I have tried setting iisSettings to have windows authentication. Enabling CORS in the program.cs file, and adding mode, header, and credentials to the fetch requests.

Comment: Please note that CORS has to run before Windows Authentication if the server isn't configured to allow anonymous access. On local, for dev and testing purpose,  can try to enable anonymous authentication to allow anonymous access. On IIS side, the IIS CORS module needs to be installed and configured for the app. For more information, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cors-in-iis